# Varnish redirect loop (trying to send non-www to www)

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, varnish

I'm trying to redirect requests with no 'www' to www.mydomain.com (a WordPress site) in Varnish, but for some reason can only create an infinite loop of redirects. In my Varnish vcl I have:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "example.com") {
        set req.http.host = "www.example.com";
        error 750 "http://" + req.http.host + req.url;
    }

    ...
```

and:

```
sub vcl_error {
    if (obj.status == 750) {
        set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
        set obj.status = 301;
        return(deliver);
    }
}
```

(this is taken from examples I've seen online). In Fiddler the responses seem to show Varnish doing the right thing:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 http://www.example.com/
Server: Varnish
Location: http://example.com/
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 17 Dec 2014 12:42:56 GMT
X-Varnish: 1488505994
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
```

but nonetheless, it loops until the browser gives up. What am I overlooking? Any tips much appreciated.

Toby

Comment: in the settings wordpress gives you the option where to redicrect. Why do you make you own functions...

Comment: The request hits Varnish before Apache, and before WordPress, by redirecting there we are (presumably) more efficient

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job really. Get your web server to decide about redirects. Use Varnish to cache them.

Comment: What is your primary domain for wordpress? with or without www?

Comment: primary domain is with www

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using Varnish <4, as in 4 the syntax is sightly different.

But the problem is that even though your vcl seems to be correct, the log seems to show the opposite thing, a request for http://www.example.com/ being redirected to http://example.com/, and later you say that your primary domain is www. The vcl and wordpress disagree about the main domain.

Make sure that you are reloading and using the correct vcl, and also make sure that you have written the correct hosts in the vcl and that wordpress agrees.

Show a varnishlog trace if you aren't able to find the problem.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I'm using Varnish 3.05. I also think that Varnish may not have been the issue, I think it's something at the web server (Apache) level that I've overlooked. Thanks for your interest though.